# GitHub Actions. How to find out which dependency is missing?

Tags: laravel, github, github-actions

I'm trying out GitHub Actions "Workflows" for the first time. I'm following the documentation.

However when my action workflow runs, it fails with composer saying:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.

(See Screenshot)

Is there a way I can find out what dependency it's failing on? I'm trying this with the default "laravel" starter action.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `-q` (or --quiet) from the command line arguments:

**[From composer cli docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options)**

> --quiet (-q): Do not output any message.